# Return all Mondays between two dates while excluding certain dates from an array

Tags: php, for-loop, datetime, while-loop, strtotime

In php, return all Mondays between two dates. However, exclude certain dates as needed/listed. Then, show all dates, but use the "strike" tag in html to display the dates from the excluded list.

This code returns a decent result, but there must be a more eloquent solution that uses the DateTime functions and a possibly a list of dates to exclude as an array.

```
`$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this monday'));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2024-05-06'));
$endDate = strtotime($endDate);
for($i = strtotime('Monday', strtotime($startDate)); $i <= $endDate; $i = strtotime('+1 week', $i)) {
  if ( $i != strtotime('Monday', strtotime('2024-02-19')) &&
    $i != strtotime('Monday', strtotime('2024-03-25')) &&
    $i != strtotime('Monday', strtotime('2024-05-13')) ) {
      echo "<li>";
        echo date('D. M. jS', $i);
      echo "</li>";
    } else {
      // strike through the excluded dates with <s> tag
      echo "<li><s>";
        echo date('D. M. jS', $i);
      echo "</s></li>";
    }
}`
```

Comment: "*there must be a more eloquent solution that uses the DateTime functions*" - a quick search confirms your suspicions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061802/php-function-for-get-all-mondays-within-date-range, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653891/how-to-find-number-of-mondays-or-tuesdays-between-two-dates, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244875/how-to-get-the-dates-for-all-mondays-between-two-dates-but-only-for-whole-weeks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688043/how-to-get-monday-and-wednesday-dates-of-every-2-week-between-two-dates, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the code using `DateTime` like below

```php
$startDate = new DateTime('this monday');
$endDate = new DateTime('2024-05-06');
$excludedDates = ['2024-02-19', '2024-03-25', '2024-05-13'];

$currentDate = clone $startDate;

while ($currentDate <= $endDate) {
    if (!in_array($currentDate->format('Y-m-d'), $excludedDates) && $currentDate->format('l') === 'Monday') {
        echo "<li>" . $currentDate->format('D. M. jS') . "</li>";
    } else {
        echo "<li><s>" . $currentDate->format('D. M. jS') . "</s></li>";
    }

    $currentDate->modify('+1 week');
}
```